# Can the Yarn 2 Constraints feature block the installation of a package?

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces, yarnpkg-v2, yarn-v2

I have a deep dependency tree. Some of the packages depend on nodejs packages that I don't need. Is it possible for Yarn 2 (berry) to skip those packages, i.e. not install them?

Yarn has a [Constraints](https://yarnpkg.com/features/constraints) feature, but I don't know what's possible with it. There are examples, but not for ignoring a package completely.

Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constraints allow you to enforce rules on the dependency your project (and workspaces) have. It's a tool for writing rules that are applied to what goes in your various `package.json` files, like "every workspace must have the same version of react" or "no workspace may depend on package X".

If you have a dependency that is depending on something that you believe is really an optional dependency, you can use `.yarnrc` to change that dependency into an optional one. Use `yarn why <foo>` find the package that is causing the unwanted deep dependency, and then add something like this to `.yarnrc` (specific example yoinked from [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11982#issuecomment-1065855134)):

```
# Make `eslint-plugin-flowtype`'s peerDependency on `@babel/plugin-syntax-flow` optional.
# Use `dependenciesMeta` for non-peer deps, of course ;).
packageExtensions:
  'eslint-plugin-flowtype@*':
    peerDependenciesMeta:
      '@babel/plugin-syntax-flow':
        optional: true
```

Note that doing this is in general quite risky: you should probably be filing a bug upstream if you think a package is depending on something that should really be an optional dependency.

Lastly, note that it's very possible this whole thing is a non-problem: webpack (or whatever bundler is in fashion a week after I write this) is probably deleting the unwanted files at compile-time anyway? If you find the mere presence of the node packages you don't like is causing issues (eg. via typescript typings?) then that's a different problem that should be solved differently.